# I want the raw data that can be accessed by further clicking on a link

Tags: selenium-webdriver, button, beautifulsoup, click

I want the raw data that can be accessed by further clicking on a link. 
Here is the process: 
1) click on the link (https://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/interactive/) 
2) Select "Dynamic : Conterminous " or second option from the Edition panel 
3) import latitude and longitude as 35 and -90 
4) hit Compute Hazard Curve
5) hit Compute Deaggregation
6) hit Download Deaggregation Report

Now I need all the information in the Deaggregation Report. It will be graet if I can download it as a text file to further process it with Python 3.7

Python

I only need the source data from the right URL

Output should be a text file that needs further evaluations!

Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Chrome driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/interactive/')

xpath =' /html/body/main/div/div/section[2]/div/section/ul[1]/li[1]/label/select'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.send_keys('Dynamic: Conterminous U.S. 2014 (v4.1.1)')

xpath = '//*[@id="input-latitude"]'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.send_keys(35)

xpath = '//*[@id="input-longitude"]'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.send_keys(-90)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[1]/p/button'
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
btn.click()

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/button'
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
btn.click()
```

Click button is no enabled facing following error:

> Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

after further clicking I should be able to download the text!

Comment: Where is your code to show your attempts and the current issue you are facing? It sounds like you are treating SO like a code writing service (it is not).

Comment: Hi JeffC, Please see the code that I have uploaded!

Comment: That's much better. Have you googled what a stale element reference is? Do you understand what it is and what causes it? It's a very common error and there are already many resources on the web and existing on SO that discuss this. You should spend some time understanding what it is and try some of the proposed solutions that you find. Once you've done that, come back and edit your question to show what you tried and what didn't work, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver


# Inputs
Latitude = 34
Longitude = -90
Vs30 = 2000
Period = 0.2
Return_period = 2000

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Chrome driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/interactive/')
driver.implicitly_wait(15)


xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[2]/div/section/ul[1]/li[1]/label/select'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.send_keys('Dynamic: Conterminous U.S. 2014 (v4.1.1)')

xpath = '//*[@id="input-latitude"]'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.send_keys(Latitude)

xpath = '//*[@id="input-longitude"]'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.send_keys(Longitude)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[2]/div/section/ul[1]/li[3]/label/select'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

if Vs30 == 760:
    Site_Class = '760 m/s (B/C boundary)'
else:
    Site_Class = '2000 m/s (Site class A)'          

box.send_keys(Site_Class)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[2]/div/section/ul[2]/li[1]/label/select'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

if Period == 0:
   Spectral_period = 'Peak ground acceleration'
elif Period == 0.2:
   Spectral_period = '0.2 sec spectral acceleration'
elif Period == 1.0:
   Spectral_period = '1.0 sec spectral acceleration'
else:
   Spectral_period = '2.0 sec spectral acceleration'

box.send_keys(Spectral_period)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[2]/div/section/ul[2]/li[2]/label/input'
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
box.clear()
box.send_keys(Return_period)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[1]/p/button'
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
btn.click()

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[1]/p/button'
btn1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
btn1.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)


xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/dl/dd[3]'
Intensity = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
Intensity = float(Intensity[0:-1])

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[4]/dl/dd[1]'
R_mean = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
R_mean = float(R_mean[0:-2])

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[4]/dl/dd[2]'
M_mean = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
M_mean = float(M_mean)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[4]/dl/dd[3]'
Epsilon_mean = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
Epsilon_mean = float(Epsilon_mean[0:-1])

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[5]/dl/dd[1]'
R_mode = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
R_mode = float(R_mode[0:-2])

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[5]/dl/dd[2]'
M_mode = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
M_mode = float(M_mode)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[5]/dl/dd[3]'
Epsilon_mode = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
Epsilon_mode = float(Epsilon_mode[0:-1])

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[6]/dl/dd[1]'
R_mode_eps = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
R_mode_eps = float(R_mode_eps[0:-2])

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[6]/dl/dd[2]'
M_mode_eps = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
M_mode_eps = float(M_mode_eps)

xpath = '/html/body/main/div/div/section[4]/div/section/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[6]/dl/dd[3]'
Epsilon_mode_eps = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
Epsilon_mode_eps = float(Epsilon_mode_eps[0:-1])
driver.close()

[Latitude , Longitude , Return_period,  Period , Site_Class,  Intensity, M_mean , R_mean , Epsilon_mean,  M_mode, R_mode, Epsilon_mode, M_mode_eps, R_mode_eps, Epsilon_mode_eps]
```